# How should I set SQLite3 DB permissions on a live website?

Tags: database, sqlite, permissions

I'm trying to set up a tiny web app on a live website using SQLite 3.

In order to get PHP to talk to it on my local server, I had to do `chmod 777` on the database file, or it wouldn't allow me to write to it.

If it's on a live site, though, I don't want it to be `777` because anybody can download the database (if they know/guess the path).

How can I restrict access to it and still be able to write to the database file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can restrict the database download by .htaccess rule.

put an .htaccess file in the db directory with this:

Order deny,allow
deny from all

then, nobody can download the database.